# Show that the constant map from $Y$ to $\mathcal{L}Y$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification

Let $\mathcal{L}Y$ denote the free loop space of $Y$. I want to show that $f:Y\rightarrow \mathcal{L}Y$ such that $y \mapsto(\theta\in S^1\mapsto y\in Y)$ is continuous.

My attempt:
We want to show that $f\in \text{Cts}(Y, \text{Cts}(S^1,Y))$. By the adjunction property, if we can show that some function that is in $\text{Cts}(Y\times S^1,Y)$ that has the same property then we know that this function is continuous.

Let the function $\pi:Y\times S^1\rightarrow Y$ be the projection map s.t. $F(y,\theta) = y$ then this function is continuous. Then by the adjunction property, we know that the function $f:Y\rightarrow \mathcal{L}Y$ is having the property $f(y)(\theta) = y$ such that $F$ corresponds to $f$. Hence $f$ is continuous.

Is this correct? Since I am new to function space so if there is anything unclear, please give me some suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about the free loop space as dicussed on [ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+loop+space), this doesn't seem to be that hard. $\mathcal{L}Y$ is just the space of all continuous functions from $S^1$ to $Y$ in the compact-open topology (subbasic open subsets are of the form $$[C,U]:=\{f: S^1 \to Y\mid f \text{ continuous and } f[C] \subseteq U\}$$ where $C$ is a (non-empty)  compact subset of $X$ and $U$ a (non-empty) open subset of $Y$).

Denote by $c_y$ the constant map with value $y$ in $\mathcal{L}Y$, so that $f(y)=c_y$ by definition, and note that by the defintions $c_y \in [C,U]$ iff $y \in U$.

Proof of continuity: let $[C,U]$ be a subbasic open subset of $\mathcal{L}Y$ (so $C \subseteq S^1$ is compact and $U \subseteq Y$ is open). Then $$f^{-1}[[C,U]] = \{y \in Y\mid c_y \in [C,U]\} = \{y \in Y\mid y \in U\}=U$$ and so inverse images of subbasic sets under $f$ are open in $Y$ and so $f$ is continuous by standard results.

Comment: For the "denote by cy..." part, does that mean since $c_y$ is a continuous function from $S^1$ to $Y$ then it must be in some $[C,U]$ such that it forces $y\in U$?

Comment: And $y \in U$ because if $c_y \in [C,U]$ then $c_y(K) \subseteq U$ but since $c_y$ maps to the constant, $c_y(K) = \{y\}\subseteq U$?

Comment: @Ming yes if $c_y$ is in any $[C,U]$ (it will be in some and not in others) then for any $x\in C$, we have $y=c_y(x) \in c_y[C]\subseteq U$.